Generalized edge map in spectral sequence of double complex
suppose we have a cohomologically indexed double complex $C^{\bullet,\bullet}$ with its spectral sequence
$$E_2^{p,q}=H^p_{vert}(H^q_{horiz}(C))\Rightarrow H^{p+q}(C)$$
and suppose that the horizontal cohomology of $C$ vanishes above degree $k$. Then there should be a generalized edge map
$$
H^n(C)\to H^{n-k}_{vert}(H^k_{horiz}(C)).
$$
I want a description of this edge map in terms of "take a representative of a class in the total cohomology, modify it so that certain components are closed, then this component will represent the image of the edge map." I figured out how to do this from scratch with some diagram chasing, but I'm assuming these edge maps are described in the literature somewhere, and would prefer to cite a source. Anybody have one?
